# Which path to use for Python project interpreter?

Tags: python, ide, project, virtualenv, interpreter

When creating a virtual environment for Python, to which path should the project interpreter in the IDE point to? To **/venv/bin** or **/venv/local/bin?** Or doesn't it really matter? Because the contents of both directories are identical...

Thanks in advance for any clarification!

K.

```
tst@apollo:~$ virtualenv tst
New python executable in tst/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
tst@apollo:~$ ls tst/bin
activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  activate_this.py  easy_install  easy_install-2.7  pip  pip2  pip2.7  python  python2  python2.7
tst@apollo:~$ ls tst/local/bin
activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  activate_this.py  easy_install  easy_install-2.7  pip  pip2  pip2.7  python  python2  python2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it doesn't matter...

The **venv/local/bin** directory appears to be a link to the **venv/bin** directory, so it's okay to use either of the directories to configure the project interpreter.

I guess that answers my question. :-)

```
tst@apollo:~$ ls -lsa tst/local/bin
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 csf csf 20 Oct  2 17:06 tst/local/bin -> /home/tst/tst/bin
```